# Launching an install4j installer from within another install4j installer in console mode

Tags: install4j

I have an installer A.  When it runs it launches installer B using the "Run executable or batch file" action.

In GUI mode this runs fine.

However, on headless Ubuntu (or passing the -c flag) the installation hangs.
Looking at the log file of installer B it looks like it is attempting to run the "Welcome Screen" even though it should run in console mode:

```
[INFO] com.....install4j.extensions.WelcomeFormPanelScreen [ID WelcomeScreen]: Show screen
```

The log for installer A clearly shows the -c flag was passed:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction [ID 21125]: Execute action
   Property environmentVariables: {}       
   Property returnCodeVariable: 
   Property rollbackArguments: null
   Property rollbackExecutable: null
   Property rollbackWorkingDirectory: null
   Property stderrFile: null
   Property stderrRedirectionMode: No redirection
   Property waitForStreams: false
   Property stderrVariableName: 
   Property stdinFile: null
   Property stdinString: 
   Property stdoutFile: null
   Property stdoutRedirectionMode: No redirection
   Property stdoutVariableName: 
   Property workingDirectory: /opt/folder
   Property failOnStderrFileError: false
   Property failOnStdinFileError: false
   Property failOnStdoutFileError: false
   Property includeParentEnvironmentVariables: true
   Property keepConsoleWindow: true
   Property logArguments: true
   Property showWindowsConsole: true
   Property useRollbackExecutable: false
   Property wait: true
   Property stdinRedirectionMode: No redirection
   Property timeout: 0
   Property arguments: [-c]
```

When I run installer B by itself from the command line with the -c option it runs in console mode without issues.

Has anyone else run into this issue or knows of a workaround?

Thanks,
Bella

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has had this issue - I contacted install4j support and was told that:

> "You would have to start it with the -q flag. Nesting installers in console mode is not supported by install4j."

Comment: I already start it using the -q flag but it doesn't work for me. I have exactly the same problem as you had, on a CentOS. Did this solve your problem ?