# running updater in console mode in install4j

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j (version 5.1.15) to build our application installer and i have started trying updater with silent version check. Everything works fine in GUI mode but in console mode, updater download the new version of my application and when it asked to proceed with the upgrade it won't launch the installer application. i'm wondering is this related to [Launching an install4j installer from within another install4j installer in console mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582951/launching-an-install4j-installer-from-within-another-install4j-installer-in-cons)
or am i doing something wrong

Comment: Try to start the updater with -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true and check the log file in the %TEMP% directory.

Comment: @IngoKegel, i get ShutdownCallingLauncherAction error with no shutdown file property. do you know what that means?

Comment: i get the same error in GUI mode but it launches the new version of the application

Comment: Try starting the installer from the updater with -q flag instead of the -c flag. There us an action on the "Finish" screen of the updater that sets the arguments for the installer.

Comment: @IngoKegel, It works with -q but still fails with -c and i found out that when its run with -c command installer fails with usercanceledException. This happens during a script that i have added to check version. In there user is prompted to either update or update later option. So in there user needs to select option. It works with -c when i run the installer directly, but run through updater, it fails. I'm not sure how to fix this

Comment: @IngoKegel, it seems like when installer called through updater in console mode in linux, it fails to run the installer in the same shell, so installed get canceled. Is this a limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 6 and earlier it was not possible to for a sub-process to inherit the  I/O of the parent process, it was only connected to the parent process via pipes. This made is impossible to do console IO with nested processes. In Java 7 ProcessBuilder has new methods that allow a sub-process to share the I/O environment with the parent process.

install4j 6.1 will take advantage of those features. Right now there is no workaround for this problem.

Comment: thanks for the info. When will the version 6.1 available?