# launching nested installer in console mode

Tags: install4j

Wondering if anything has changed since this post from a few years ago:

[Launching an install4j installer from within another install4j installer in console mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582951/launching-an-install4j-installer-from-within-another-install4j-installer-in-cons)

I need to find a way to launch nested installers in console mode on Windows. 
I'm trying to use

```
start/ wait installer.exe -c
```

using install4j v5.1.15

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a "Run executable" action?

Comment: I was unable to find a way to stay in console mode when an .exe is nested within another. I'm using a work around to avoid using the main installer in which the components are nested. It would be great if there was a way to stay in console.

Comment: In newer versions you can set the "Redirect stdout" and "Redirect stdin" properties of the "Run executable or batch file" action to "Inherit parent handle", then you can nest installers on the command line.

Comment: Ok, that is good information, I will look into upgrading to the latest version. Thanks!